# Morphisms of jacobians

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

If $X$ and $Y$ are two complex curves then we have
$${\rm Pic}(X\times Y) \ \simeq \ {\rm Pic}(X)\times {\rm Pic}(Y)\times {\rm Hom}(J_X,J_Y) \ ,$$
where $J_X$, $J_Y$ are the jacobians of $X$, $Y$.

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are distinct curves of genus $\geq 2$. Then do we have  ${\rm Hom}(J_X,J_Y)=0$, always, or for generic curves ?

I have another question: we have anyway  $H^1({\mathcal O}_{X\times Y})\simeq H^1({\mathcal O}_X)\oplus H^1({\mathcal O}_Y)$. This suggests that the subgoup ${\rm Hom}(J_X,J_Y)$ of ${\rm Pic}(X\times Y)$ should be discrete. Is it true that the deformations of a line bundle $L$ coming from ${\rm Hom}(J_X,J_Y)$ are of the for $L\otimes \pi_X^*(L_X)\otimes\pi_Y^*(L_Y)$, where $\pi_X$, $\pi_Y$ are the projections $X\times Y\to X,Y$, and $L_X\in{\rm Pic}(X)$,  $L_Y\in{\rm Pic}(Y)$ ?

Comment: Surely not always, any morphism $X\to Y$ induces a map $J_X\to J_Y$. I suspect it may hold generically though.

Comment: @Wojowu  Any nonconstant morphism of smooth projective curves both having equal genus $g>1$ is automatically an isomorphism (by Riemann-Hurwitz).  However, your point is well-taken: consider $X$ and $Y$ covers of a common elliptic curve.

Comment: More generally, if $X$ and $Y$ map onto a common curve of positive genus, then $Hom(J_X, J_Y)\not=0$. If one of them is generic, then it should be true. I don't really have time to write  a proof right now.

Comment: @DonuArapura Sorry, what should be true?

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly I meant that when either $X$ or $Y$ is general, then it should be true that $Hom(J_X,J_Y)=0$.

Comment: I think Donu Arapura's statement holds when both $X$ and $Y$ are general. This follows from the fact that a generic curve has simple Jacobian. Over the complex numbers, one can see this from monodromy considerations: the moduli space is Teichmüller space modulo the mapping class group. The mapping class group is generated by Dehn twists. On the other hand, the corresponding symplectic group is generated by the images of those Dehn twists (called symplectic transcriptions). I think Ekedahl has written a proof of the simplicity of the general Jacobian for arbitrary algebraically closed fields.

Comment: Be careful, if $g = 2, 3$ something funny happens!

Comment: @Raju: The simplicity of the Jacobian does not imply this. As pointed out by Johan, for $g = 2,3$, even though the generic Jacobian is simple, the claim is not true. For $g > 3$ it is probably true, but this requires some extra arguments.

Comment: Oops, thanks! I somehow had in my mind that the curves had different genera.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I have added a supplement to my question.

Comment: I was too hasty in my previous comments, but I'll leave them up for context.

Comment: I think what @Johan is trying to get at is when $g = 2,3$ every principally polarized abelian variety is the Jacobian of some curve by dimensional reasons. The dimension of $\mathcal{M}_g$ is $3g - 3$ and that of ppavs is $\frac{g(g+1)}{2}$. When $g = 2,3$ these numbers match up and when $g > 3$ they are strictly unequal.